# Symfony CLI php.ini

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any way to use the php.ini of the Symfony Local Web server to overwrite the parameters used in the php cli command?

I want to run php bin/console commands with the configs present in my local php.ini instead of the global php.ini file.

Comment: As an option, you can use `-c <file|path>` to instruct PHP to scan for additional .ini files.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: Thanks! does the file need to be a full php.ini file? because the php.ini from the symfony server just needs the lines you want to overwrite.